# Multilevel ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have a database with the schema:

```
A - String
B - String
C - Int
D - Int
```

And the database is

```
 A  |  B  | C | D 
------------------
'F' | 'a' | 1 | 2
'F' | 'a' | 1 | 4
'F' | 'b' | 2 | 4
'Z' | 'a' | 3 | 7
'Z' | 'b' | 4 | 3
'Z' | 'a' | 6 | 5
```

And I want something along the lines of

## F

**a**   2   6 
**b**   2   4

## Z

**a**   9   12 
**b**   4   3

So essentially, group by `A`, then group by `B`, and `SUM(C), SUM(D)`. How can I do this in ActiveRecord?

Comment: Perhaps you can start by writing the SQL you'd like to execute. If you put that in there, I'd be willing to show you how you generate that with Arel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AR solution:

```
things = Thing.select('a, b, sum(c) as sum_c, sum(d) as sum_d').group(:a, :b)

things.each do |thing| 
  puts "#{thing.a} / #{thing.b} / #{thing.sum_c} / #{thing.sum_d}" 
end

# F / a / 2 / 6
# F / b / 2 / 4
# Z / a / 9 / 12
# Z / b / 4 / 3
```

You can dynamically create properties in your AR classes (see `as sum_c`). Depending on what you do this might be easier/nicer with straight SQL.